# Numeric sort by the column values

Tags: sort, numeric-data

For example I have some test file and want to sort it by the column values. After

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{print $16}' test.json
```

I get next output for the column 16:

```
 123
 457
 68
 11
 939
 11
 345
 9
 199
 13745
```

Now, when I want to sort it numeric, I use

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{print $16}' test.json | sort -nk16
```

but I just get back not nummeric sort...

```
 11
 11
 123
 13745
 199
 345
 457
 68
 9
 939
```

What is a reason, I thought `-n` parameter is enough for the nummeric sort....

Comment: Just `sort -n`. There's no 16th column in that output of `awk`

Comment: Yes, it works. thank you. Anyway, if I want to sort the whole file by column 16, what I need to change in my command? Firstly I want create columns and sort by specific column the whole file.

Comment: @Guforu you almost make it, try `sort -nk16 test.json `

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work... I should first create a columns

Comment: What do you mean by "create a columns"? Do you want to turn the : and , separators into spaces? Do you need the columns to line up in a readable format? Please be specific.

Comment: I'm very sorry, it works! I just calculate wrong the right column number! Everything allright, thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `awk` contains only one column, so no 16th column.

So `sort` sees all identical empty sort keys and what you observe is the result of the last resort sort (lexical sort on the whole line) which you can disable with the `-s` option in some implementations.

Here you want:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{print $16}' test.json | sort -n
```

Now, if you want to sort the file on the 16<sup>th</sup> column, beware `sort` supports only one character column delimiter, so you'd need to preprocess the input:

```
sed 's/[:,]/&+/g' test.json | sort -t+ -k16,16n | sed 's/\([:,]\)+/\1/g'
```

Here appending a `+` to every `:` or `,`, sorting with `+` as the column delimiter and removing the `+` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Anyway, what @Achemar tell, is also correct.

Comment: @Guforu, `sort`'s default column delimiter is the transition between a non-blank and a blank. So `-k16n` numerically sorts on the part of the line that goes from the 15th occurrence of that to the end of the line. For instance, in a line like `" a b, 1 d, 2 e"`, `-k3n` would consider `" 1 d, 2 e"` as the sort key. Because of `n`, that's treated as `1`, so `-k3n` is the same as `-bk3,3n`.